# Add flash animations to Xcode?

Tags: xcode, flash, animation

For my application, there are many features that need to include animations. For example, while loading a ViewController, I need the images and buttons that appear on the screen an intricate Animations that cannot be done in Xcode. So far, I have made only simple animations through Xcode such as shrinking images, buttons moving to a CGPoint, etc. Simple things. If I make these intricate animations in Adobe Flash or another animation software, is there anyway to incorporate it within my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple dod not support flash on iphone or ipad.only youtube can be played. if you want to use any animation make a gif or use HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the nature of your application, you could consider writing the application using Flash, and then use Adobe AIR to compile it to run natively on iPhone and iPad.  Best of all, Adobe AIR could also compile it to run on Android, Blackberry Playbook and traditional Windows and Mac, so you can write once and run everywhere.  By doing so, you can also take advantage of the animation power of Flash.